# Stretch image to fill div, but not skew

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to make an image stretch to fit inside a div. However I want it to overflow so that the entire div is filled. The div resizes with the page. I want an effect similar to the jQuery bgstretcher plugin (http://www.ajaxblender.com/bgstretcher-2-jquery-stretch-background-plugin-updated.html) , but I cannot use that plugin because I'm already using it for the background image on the page, and it seems to not work when you try and activate multiple instances of it.

So what I'm asking is for some sort of simple jQuery function that resizes an image to completely fill a div with overflow hidden, so that there are no gaps, but without skewing the image.

**Edit:**

http://jsfiddle.net/R7UCZ/

That's sort of what I'm after, but I want the image to *fill* the entire div *without* skewing. If the image goes out of the div a bit, that's fine, but I need it to resize with the div, which resizes with the page, both height and width.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First you need to get the image properties and see which one is larger, the height or the width, then resize the image based on the div size after the window resizes, like this:

```
  //this would load up initially, you will need this data for future processing


   div = $("div");
   imgsrc = div.find('img').attr('src');

   var img = new Image()
   img.onload = function(){
        imgw = img.width;
        imgh = img.height;

        //after its loaded and you got the size..
        //you need to call it the first time of course here and make it visible:

        resizeMyImg(imgw,imgh);
        div.find('img').show();

        //now you can use your resize function
        $(window).resize(function(){ resizeMyImg(imgw,imgh) });

        }
   img.src = imgsrc


   function resizeMyImg(w,h){     
      //the width is larger
      if (w > h) {
        //resize the image to the div
        div.find('img').width(div.innerWidth() + 'px').height('auto');
      }        
      else {
        // the height is larger or the same
        //resize the image to the div
        div.find('img').height(div.innerHeight() + 'px').width('auto');
      }

     }
```

You can actually find a complete solution here:
http://jsfiddle.net/CDywS/1

Answer (score 6):

You do not need JavaScript/jQuery at all. Just use the `contain` or `cover` values for `background-size`:

1. `background-size: contain` scales the image to it's maximum width/height so that the whole image is visible while preserving aspect ratio. (no overflow)
2. `background-size: cover` scales the image to it's maxium width so that the whole div is filled with the image while preserving aspect ratio. (overflow if image is not square)

Therefore, you just need to write this code:

```
#myDiv {
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Or:

```
#myDiv {
    background-size: cover;
}
```

More information: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

**Update**: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/R7UCZ/2/)

Comment: but it's not a background image. That's wonderful! I didn't know that, but it's an image *inside* a div.

Comment: maybe you could create a demo on jsfiddle.net so that i get a clearer view of what you are trying to do

Comment: `background-size` is part of CSS3 and is not supported by IE5, IE6, IE7, or IE8 (http://www.quirksmode.org/css/background.html).

Answer (score 1):

Zee Tee's answer is marked as correct and it does do the job - but only for landscape oriented images. Portrait images don't work with it, as you can see if you try such an image in the jsfiddle example.

However, you can make it work, by giving the div containing the image a height. You can give either a fixed value for this or a min-height, either will work.

The reason for this is that in the resizeMyImg function, in the line:

```
div.find('img').height(div.innerHeight() + 'px').width('auto');
```

div.innerHeight is undefined unless the div has a height or min-height CSS attribute associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do like this:

```
 <img src="your_picture.png" alt="" style="width:100%;height:100%"></img>
```

And when your container div resizes the image will stretch itself to fill the entire div.

**EDIT:**

If you don't want the image to skew:

```
 <img src="your_picture.png" alt="" style="width:100%"></img>
```

Or:

```
 <img src="your_picture.png" alt="" style="height:100%"></img>
```

Depending on which dimension you don't want to overflow...

Comment: I'm trying to get the whole image to fill the div **with out** skewing. so if the edge of the image goes out of the div a bit that's fine, so long as it doesn't skew.